# iOS Secure Transport TLS extensions

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, tls1.2, secure-transport

I am developing an application that talks to a peer via a secure channel. The data is secured via Apple's Secure Transport Framework. I am actually trying to remove the TLS extensions from the Client Hello message by configuring the SSLContextRef object but the extensions remained.

Is it possible to remove TLS extensions from the Client Hello message that is sent to the server ? If possible then what are the extensions that can be configured ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a code package for handling TLS that takes into account the new TLS restrictions imposed by apple for iOS 13. Here is a link:

https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/IOSObjCWebSockets

With how I structure things, the point in the code you want to change is probably here (if you are using Network.h package):

```
nw_parameters_configure_protocol_block_t configure_tls = NW_PARAMETERS_DISABLE_PROTOCOL;

nw_parameters_t parameters = nw_parameters_create_secure_tcp(
    configure_tls,
    NW_PARAMETERS_DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION
);
```

Instead of a long confusing `configure_tls` block (like in my code), if you want to disable TLS, you can pass `NW_PARAMETERS_DISABLE_PROTOCOL` in place of where you would pass the `configure_tls` block (if you were to configure a secure connection). Hope this helps.